# Unity rename public fields to keep assignments

Tags: unity-game-engine

how can I rename a field in a Unity script, but keep it's assignment in the Unity Editor inspector?
Say I have

```
public int x;
```

I assign "1" to x in the inspctor and then i rename x to y in the script. The assignment will then be lost. Is there a way to keep it?

I'm using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing the following will save the value in the inspector. It can be removed after the scene has been saved again.

```
[FormerlySerializedAs("x")]
public int y;
```

[Read more about it here](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/02/03/renaming-serialized-fields/) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serialization.FormerlySerializedAsAttribute.html)

Comment: Uh. Not as comfortable as I hoped it would be, but it works, nice. :)

Comment: do not forget to import `using UnityEngine.Serialization;`

Comment: I am applying this attribute `[FormerlySerializedAs("x")]` with the provided namespace as well. I do not need to save the scene but just properly reference the old field name in the parameter. Works great

Answer (score 2):

Some additional information on this that may come handy. Renaming is not the only scenario you will need this. If your encapsulate the field you also need to do this.

```
public int y;
```

Encapsulate

```
[FormerlySerializedAs("x")]
//[FormerlySerializedAs("a")] //-has support for multiple renames.
[SerializeField]
private int x;
```