# Unity3d - C# - How can I back up of values of an array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Defined an array of 67 elements in a script (C#).
Each element is an object of a class that I defined that includes some variables.
Like Below:

```
// the Definition of the array
public Pack[] packsInfo;

// the class 
[Serializable]
public class Pack
{
    public int number;
    public int angle;
    public float zPosition;
    public float beatCaseDistance;
    public float gunDistance;
}
```

Then, I Assign all the values in Inspector. like Below:

[image]

So ... if i suddenly change any of the values or even worse, ( the values gone for a any reason. like changing the class parameters or any thing ) then I must spend hours on setting up all the values. 
So i want to print all the values in a text, or a file and save them. for recovering them later. i want a backup solution.I want to do it whit Programming. ( I don't want to write them manually ;) .It is waste of time. )

Comment: Here's an answer to how to keep the values when renaming a field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761310/unity-rename-public-fields-to-keep-assignments/40761550#40761550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save yor array you can use for example [JsonUtillity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/710).

It is simple! Good Luck!

```
 void Start () {
    /////////////////////// save to json
    JSONObject jsonSave = new JSONObject();
    for(int i=0; i < packsInfo.Length; i++) {
        JSONObject packJson = new JSONObject();
        packJson.AddField("number", packsInfo[i].number);
        packJson.AddField("angle", packsInfo[i].angle);
        packJson.AddField("z_position", packsInfo[i].zPosition);
        packJson.AddField("beat_case_distance", packsInfo[i].beatCaseDistance);
        packJson.AddField("gun_distance", packsInfo[i].gunDistance);
        jsonSave.Add(packJson);
    }

    System.IO.StreamWriter streamWritter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\MyGameFiles\packs.json");
    streamWritter.WriteLine(jsonSave.Print(true));
    streamWritter.Close();
    streamWritter = null;
    /////////////////////// read json
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\MyGameFiles\packs.json");
    string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    reader = null;

    JSONObject jsonRead = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    packsInfo = new Pack[jsonRead.Count];
    for(int i =0; i < jsonRead.Count; i ++) {
        Pack pack = new Pack();
        pack.number = (int)jsonRead[i]["number"].i;
        pack.angle = (int)jsonRead[i]["angle"].i;
        pack.zPosition = jsonRead[i]["z_position"].f;
        pack.beatCaseDistance =jsonRead[i]["beat_case_distance"].f;
        pack.gunDistance = jsonRead[i]["gun_distance"].f;
        packsInfo[i] = pack;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I test the first part and it worked perfect. and i think the rest of it will also work. It is probably to simplest and best and nearest answer to what i want and need. i needed a path because I need different packsInfo for different levels. So I can Define two public variables for name and path and easily make different JSON files. also backup them.(thanks to your simple and customizable solution).

Comment: I have a question about the code that you written. In These to Lines:  
1)pack.number = (int)jsonRead[i]["number"].i;                   
2)pack.zPosition = jsonRead[i]["z_position"].f;                 what is the ".i" and ".f" for? unity gives an error for ".i" but "not for ".f" !! are you want to specified  the "int" and "float" types?

Comment: @Armamedia `.i` returns `long` type. Because i using cast from long to int **`int i = (int)json["number"].i`**. Why is there no have fields or methods with returned `int` value? I don't know! But you can create it in `JSONObject.cs` somethink like this: `public int Int{ get { return (int)i; } }`

Comment: I delete it and write it manually and it solved!!!!!! :D)) . I don't know why but thank you.

Comment: @Armamedia Das ist gut! Plz mark my answer as solved if you a using my example)

Comment: Sure! I forgot it. sorry.

Comment: sorry I have to remove the mark. i add all you said. it just remove the error. but the values don't transmit. i working on it couple of hours with helping from YouTube and ... . but the problem didn't still constant.

Comment: @Armamedia strange, very strange. I have never encountered with this problem in my project. If you cannot transmit `int` value from `(int)json["number"].i`, that means you a pitting **not** `int` value in this json field.

Comment: those int values work perfectly in my project. why they turn in to a "not int" when transmitting to Json ?! I don't know.!!!  strange for me to.

Comment: @Armamedia In `file.json` all data saved as string, and parser dont know, "this is `int`(int32) or `long`(int64)" value.

Comment: @Armamedia I guess you need read this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)).  min/max value for `int` is `-+2,147,483,647`, and for `long` is `-+9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. Do you feel the difference? And just putting parsed number in `long` will be good for perfomance when you parsing strings, than put `if` conditions in parser`.  I Don't see any problems, all works fine)

Comment: pack.number = Convert.ToInt32(jsonRead[i]["number"].ToString());              And finally the problem solved. I hope no problem goes in the way of this subject. so... I'll going to die. |-(

Comment: @Armamedia are you using unity 2017.1?  Maybe this JsonUtillity.cs not good support newest version.

Comment: i'm using v5.6.2f1 .

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating an editor script that gets all the values in your array and saves them to specified file via IO. From there you can easily make a load function with file reading.

Here's some links to get you started:

[Unity editor scripts](http://prof.johnpile.com/2015/04/06/unity3d-save-your-in-play-transform-modifications-1-of-2/)

[Unity read write file](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000341143-How-do-I-read-and-write-data-from-a-text-file-)

Comment: Thank you. I'll go for it and if it don't solved, i will ask you here again.

Comment: the nipercop's answer was good and nearest to what I need. but not the complete one.It'll be better if I have two save and load key in inspector. so I can save and load data when I truly need. and thank to you for your starting points.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has been answered many times but I would recommend you use the [Newtonsoft Json Library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). It automates the serialisation and deserialisation of objects for you so as you change the object the json will adapt without having to make specific changes.

To Serialise you simply do this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.Serialise(packsInfo); //convert to text
File.WriteAllText(path, json); //Save to disk
```

To deserialise you simply do this:

```
string json = File.ReadAllLines(path); //load the file
packsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pack[]>(json); //convert to an object
```

That's all you have to do to save and load your data. To get the Library you can use NuGet to add the library to the project. in Visual Studio Go to Tools -> NuGet package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution then go to the browse tab and search for it.

Comment: the package don't install for me!

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: I finally install it. couple of errors solved. i Uninstall and reinstall the VS in the end :). the package installed. but unity can't recognize the Newtonsoft. It throw an error on "using Newtonsoft.Json". however my problem solved throw traditional way. and i find out that Newtonsoft is so troublesome and can't be trusted,for my project at least.(and also for many people. since i search for my problem in internet.)

Comment: Oh wow, I've used it as my serialisation solution almost every time... Maybe the built in XML writer could do the trick https://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

Comment: The problem now solved. upon my project's deadline, I can't put more time on it for now. i'll checking newtonsoft and your links later.I'll write a comment whenever I check it in the future. but thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no particular reason to have the variables serialized in the editor (public) I'd advise the following steps to remove them as public:

1. Use [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) and serialize your class to json when you've set all values and print it.

.

```
var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(packsInfo);
Debug.Log(json);
```

2. Now, when you start your game the class will be displayed in your console, you can then copy that json and save it in a text file, for example "MyFile.txt"
3. Add that text file to the project and load it to your game with any of the following methods:

   - Make a public field for it and drag the file to that field:

     > public TextAsset packInfoAsset;
   - Add it to a folder called `Resources` and then use the following code to get the file:

     > var packInfoAsset = Resources.Load("MyFile"); // Note that there is no file-ending (.txt)
4. And finally, deserializing the json to your previous object, so when you load the class, in your Start-method or so, you do:

   `packsInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<Pack>(packInfoAsset);`

And there you go, you've loaded data from a file instead of having it in the editor.

Comment: thank you, it is simple and very close to what i want. But in the first step, I give just {} in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data to [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) which can be stored as asset.

Firstly, wrap your array with a ScriptableObject class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PacksInfo: ScriptableObject
{
    public Pack[] packs;
}
```

And then create an editor script to generate the ScriptableObject from Unity editor menu.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class CreatePacksInfo
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Packs Info")]
    public static PacksInfo Create()
    {
        TextAsset json = (TextAsset) 
        AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/RawData/PacksInfo.json", 
        typeof(TextAsset));
        PacksInfo asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<PacksInfo>();
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json.text, asset);

        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(asset, "Assets/Data/PacksInfo.asset");
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        return asset;
    }
}
```

In this case, I create the asset based on a json file. If you like fill them manually in Unity Editor, you can also assign your array to the PackInfo object.

When you want to use the data, you can just declare a PackInfo variable:

```
public class something: MonoBehaviour
{
    public PacksInfo packsInfo;
}
```

And then drag the ScriptableObject asset you generated directly from Unity editor to the variable in inspector.