# unity - Error In Read From JSON

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is part of a code that someone wrote for me in answer to a question:

```
JSONObject jsonRead = new JSONObject(jsonString);
packsInfo = new Pack[jsonRead.Count];
for(int i =0; i < jsonRead.Count; i ++) 
{
    Pack pack = new Pack();
    pack.number = (int)jsonRead[i]["number"].i;
    pack.angle = (int)jsonRead[i]["angle"].i;
    pack.zPosition = jsonRead[i]["z_position"].f;
    pack.beatCaseDistance =jsonRead[i]["beat_case_distance"].f;
    pack.gunDistance = jsonRead[i]["gun_distance"].f;
    packsInfo[i] = pack;
}
```

I used it in my code. Every thing worked right but these lines:

```
pack.number = (int)jsonRead[i]["number"].i;
pack.angle = (int)jsonRead[i]["angle"].i;
```

I realized that `.f` is a `get{}` method for reading float from JSON and I find nothing for reading int. And if I delete `.i`, it gives me the error that he can't convert JSON to int implicitly.

Comment: What library are you using and is it possible to link the original question that you copied this from?

Comment: This is the link ( that question is also mine ) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159836/unity3d-c-sharp-how-can-i-back-up-of-values-of-an-array

Comment: if you answer it under the original one, i can also discard this second question.

Comment: I don't really know much about that json library so I gave you an alternate answer for your original question

Answer (score 0):

`.i` returns `long` type. Because i using cast from long to int

**`int i = (int)json["number"].i`**.

Why is there no have fields or methods with returned `int` value? I don't know! **But** you can create it in `JSONObject.cs`! It will be something like this:

```
public int Int{ 
    get { 
        return (int)i; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I delete it and write it manually and it solved!!!!!! :D)) . I don't know why but thank you.